# How to solve 'Private Test Cases' PySchool

Tags: python, error-handling

Im really get confused.
Im solving PySchool Practices for university and get a problem at Topic 13: Question 2.
I need to: 
**Create a function that appends the name and email to the end of a named file.**

Code i use:

```
    # Create a function that appends the name and email to the end of a named file.
def addEmail(filename, name, email):
    f = open(filename, 'a') # replace the mode
    f.write("\n"+name+' '+email)
    # Append name and email, each record should end with '\n'.
    f.close()
    # close file
    return f # do not remove this line
```

I get:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSM08.png)
I cant understand where is my mistake.Please help.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place to ask specific questions about problems unique to a place like PySchool. Since none of us have access to said tool, we don't have the context to be able to help you.

Comment: Without context it's hard to say, but the comment `each record should end with '\n'.` might have something to do with it.

Comment: PySchool is a free platform, everyone can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code puts a newline character at the beginning of the line added to the file. However, it's very  likely that the file already has a newline character at the end of the last line to begin with.

Rather you should put you newline character at the end of the line you add. I've tried this variation; it works.

Answer (score 0):

can you check if the file is in the same directory or if it is the full file location. Also I suggest you to use with:

```
#with will close file automatically when code is done
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    # If using python 3.6 and up you can use f-String formatting  
    f.write(f'\n{name} {email}')
```

Comment: Im pretty sure this a very old version of python. And i need to use f.close() separetly.The main question is what does mean `private cases test`?

Comment: @dredd761: That tutorial system appears to reveal some of the test cases to you in the problem statement. But others are kept secret. These are referred to as its 'Private Test Cases'. If your code fails one of these then it fails the overall test.